# “‘sex’ Questions” shows up as a quick-link when I Google “parenting stack exchange”

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion, content

I Googled “parenting stack exchange” and this is what showed up:

[image]

I thought that was a little strange, but I know there’s a ‘sex’ tag, so I looked to see if it’s a popular tag to use or something... it’s not used very much, relatively speaking.

Why does that show up? And due to the fact that it’s kind of confusing that it showed up there and (in my opinion) does not accurately convey a *central* theme of Parenting SE, do we want it to show up there? Is there anything we can do about it?

Comment: I can think of almost no topic that causes parents more immediate anxiety than the sexuality/expression of their kids: how to tell kids about where they come from, kids acting out sexually, what to do if their 15 year old is dating an older boy, their kids having sex. It's right up there with tantrums in youngsters. If you don't mind 'tantrums' as a term, I don't know why 'sex' should be a particular concern. And, as @Rory Alsop stated, this has more to do with Google searches than it does with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less about Parenting.SE, and more about what searches are incredibly common on Google. Because Stack Exchange is very highly rated by Google, and we do have some questions involving sexuality that are factual, not links to porn or scam sites etc, we are placed into a category that makes us a "trusted" source for "sex" questions.

As to whether we can do anything about it - I don't know. I assume SE employees may be able to request removal of certain terms if it is an issue.

Personally, I don't think it should be a problem, and certainly when we have seen inappropriate questions we quickly close and delete them.